# How to get group names of the user is a member of using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to know the list of groups the user is a member of in AAD. Based on the membership of the group they can do another function. To achieve this I used the MS Graph API, but I get only group Ids, not the group names.
I used the following two ways using graph API.
The first method used,

```
await  graphClient.Users[upn].GetMemberGroups(false).Request().PostAsync()
```

response:

```
[ "fee2c45b-915a-4a64-b130-f4eb9e75525e", "4fe90ae7-065a-478b-9400-e0a0e1cbd540", "e0c3beaf-eeb4-43d8-abc5-94f037a65697" ]
```

The second method used,

```
await  graphClient.Users[upn].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

response:

```
[
    {
        "deletedDateTime": null,
        "id": "1c4934554-5006-403a-bf4f-bsdfeerwfs6fe6f",
        "oDataType": "#microsoft.graph.group",
        "additionalData": {
            "creationOptions": [],
            "isAssignableToRole": null,
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "deletedDateTime": null,
        "id": "f8975c2f-7651d-4f3a-1234-4ec3808a0ac2",
        "oDataType": "#microsoft.graph.group",
        "additionalData": {
            "creationOptions": [
                []
            ],
            "isAssignableToRole": null,
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
                []
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

What I need is along with the group name and group ID. How do I get both together in an efficient way? Or are there any other method which i can try for this purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me the following works for getting group names:

```cs
var page = await graphClient
    .Users[userObjectId]
    .MemberOf
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var names = new List<string>();
names.AddRange(page
        .OfType<Group>()
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)));
while (page.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    page = await page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    names.AddRange(page
        .OfType<Group>()
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)));
}

return names;
```

There should be a DisplayName/displayName in the response for groups, if permitted (e.g. `Directory.Read.All`).

Comment: Code should return names, not groupNames.
My DisplayName values are null, despite the Ids being correct for the expected groups.

Comment: Correction: I had to add Directory.Read.All permissions to my B2C app registration. Now I get the DisplayName returned.