# Querying Azure AD using Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all users for a given AD domain. Whilst I have managed to retrieve the user list successfully, the next step is to identify which groups the user is a member of.  This is where it gets hard.

**Step 1)**

```
 var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(configuration.TenantId, configuration.ClientId, ClientSecret);

 GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
 return await Task.FromResult(graphClient);
```

This gets me a successful connection to the GraphClient

```
 var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

 foreach (var user in users)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
 }
```

displays the list of users (using their DisplayName)

**Step 2)**

```
var groups = await graphClient.Users[user.Id].TransitiveMemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

This gets me the user's groups.  Finally I would like to display the actual group's name....and this is where it fails.  I am able to iterate over around groups but the only available properties are things like 'id' there is no DisplayName property.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to run the sample code :

```
var page = await graphClient
    .Users[userObjectId]
    .MemberOf
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var names = new List<string>();
names.AddRange(page
        .OfType<Group>()
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)));
while (page.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    page = await page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    names.AddRange(page
        .OfType<Group>()
        .Select(x => x.DisplayName)
        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)));
}

return names;
```

Sample question - [How to get group names of the user is a member of using Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502897/how-to-get-group-names-of-the-user-is-a-member-of-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Perfect...I don't really understand why its done this way but now I can move on.  Thank you.